# Create entry in helm template only if an entry exists in a map

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Assuming this map exists in my `values.yaml`

```
something:
   somethingElse:
       variable1: value1
       variable2: value2
       variable3: value3
```

I want to create a helm template for a `kubernetes` `Secret` resource (although this is not of primary importance) if and only if say the key - value pair `variable2: value2` exists. (I am only actually interest to match the `variable2`'s existence, not what is the value of `value2`)

I know how to `range` to include all entries

```
{{- range $name, $value := .Values.something.somethingElse }}
{{indent 4 $name }}: {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
```

but in pseudocode, what I want is

```
if variable2 in .Values.something.somethingElse

variable2: value2
```

Is this somehow feasible using the `helm` templating language?

Comment: Assuming this is the Go template language, you should be able to do: `{{if (index .Values.something.somethingElse "variable2")}}`

Comment: thanks; I will try it in a while and if it works I will let you know so that you post it as an answer which I can accept

Comment: worked like a charm, in case you want to post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
{{if (index .Values.something.somethingElse "variable2")}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Helm contain a flow control and you can create `if / else` conditional blocks, for your case this example can be helpful.

In your `values.yaml`

```
foo:
  enabled: true
```

So, in your template:

```
{{- if .Values.foo.enabled }}
 --- TEMPLATE CODE --
{{- end }}
```

Ref: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/